# How to manipulate parameters sending to remote object in CORBA using interceptors

Tags: java, corba

New to CORBA but could establish remote method invoking from a client to server. When using interceptors and try to encrypt parameters for the remote method, it throws below

```
Failed to initialise ORB: org.omg.CORBA.NO_RESOURCES:   vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1  completed: No org.omg.CORBA.NO_RESOURCES:   vmcid: OMG  minor code: 1completed: No at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.piOperationNotSupported1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.OMGSystemException.piOperationNotSupported1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.se.impl.interceptors.ClientRequestInfoImpl.arguments(Unknown Source)
at orb.CustomClientInterceptor.send_request(CustomClientInterceptor.java:23)
```

From Interceptors I'm trying to access arguments and encrypt them like below.

```
public void send_request( ClientRequestInfo ri )
{
    System.out.println( ri.arguments() );
    System.out.println( "Arguments.." );
    logger( ri, "send_request" );
}
```

But cannot even access them, it throws above error. Intercepting methods are calling fine. Could you guide me with some code or a link.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is not [tag:rmi], this is direct CORBA programming. Sadly not all of interception is supported in J2SE.

Comment: CORBA has interceptors??

Comment: @Antoniossss Certainly, both server-side and client-side. See [org.omg.PortableInterceptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/omg/PortableInterceptor/package-frame.html).

Comment: @Antoniossss check the code if you want to have an interceptor and then manipulate arguments to the remote object.

Comment: @user207421, I found that only DII and DSI calls are allowed to access and manipulate parameters for the remote object. have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and if someone hits this in future..

We cannot manipulate parameters in interceptors unless the call to CORBA object is either DII or DSI call. So first you need to make a call in either of these. I did it via DII. code is as follows.

```
                //-ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost
                Properties p = new Properties();
                p.put("org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitializerClass.orb.InterceptorORBInitializer", "");
                //ORB orb = ORB.init(args, p);

                String[] orbArgs = { "-ORBInitialHost", "localhost", "-ORBInitialPort", "1050" };
                //NO_NEED ORB orb = ORB.init( orbArgs, null );
                orb = ORB.init(orbArgs, p);
                //objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references( "NameService" );
                //ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow( objRef );

                //DII Additional configs
                org.omg.CORBA.Object ncRef = orb.resolve_initial_references ("NameService"); 
                NamingContext nc = NamingContextHelper.narrow (ncRef); 
                NameComponent nComp = new NameComponent ("ABC", ""); 
                NameComponent [] path = {nComp}; 
                objRef = nc.resolve (path);
```

Then do the DII call, I have some mixed code here but you will understand what to do

```
        NVList argList = orb.create_list (valueMap.size()); 
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : valueMap.entrySet()) {
            Any argument = orb.create_any (); 
            argument.insert_string (entry.getValue()); 
            argList.add_value (entry.getKey().toLowerCase(), argument, org.omg.CORBA.ARG_IN.value); 
        }


        //Result
        Any result = orb.create_any (); 
        result.insert_string( null ); 
        NamedValue resultVal = orb.create_named_value ("result", result, org.omg.CORBA.ARG_OUT.value); 

        //Invoking Method
        Request thisReq = objRef._create_request (null, methodName, argList, resultVal); 
        thisReq.invoke (); 

        //Extract Result
        result = thisReq.result().value ();
```

Now from the interceptors you will need to filter the DII call only and then access the parameters like below.

```
public void send_request( ClientRequestInfo ri )
{
    if(ri.operation().equals( "processPayment" ))
    {
        System.out.println( "################# CLIENT SIDE ###############" );
        int count = 0;
        for(Parameter param : ri.arguments())
        {
            System.out.println( "Arg : "+count );
            System.out.println( param.argument.extract_string());
            param.argument.insert_string( EncryptionDecryption.encrypt( param.argument.extract_string() ) );
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println( "Arguments.." );
    logger( ri, "send_request" );
}
```

Comment: Very good, well done, I battled with this for a while yearsago without finding that.